# How do you save data into cookies with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

so  I wanted to create a HTML/Javascript project which could save little bits of data even after it was closed. I had considered web hosting it on a server, but I didn't think it was worth it.

```
<script>
    var a = 1
</script>
```

So, if I had a variable a which equals 1, how would I save that data into cookies so that when I reopen the project, it turns back to 1 instead of resetting to 0 assuming that there is code that resets it? Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: You can use document.cookie

Comment: but you're probably better off using localStorage :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved now. I found out the document.cookie thing.